# Best possible schema of post, comments and replies

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am trying to figure out the schema of **post**, **comments** and **replies** to **comments**, where **replies** are only single level(no reply to reply).

**Post**:

```
1) id 2) user_id 3) contents 4) privacy
```

**comment**:

```
1) id 2) user_id 3) post_id 4) content
```

**reply**:

```
1) id 2) user_id 3) comment_id 4) content
```

What will be the possible way to minimize the queries and get best results.

Comment: Is your has ability to remove/edit his comment or reply to the comment?

Comment: all CRUDE operations are possible on post, comment and reply

Comment: Then your current database structure is fine, as Laravel provides Eloquent ORM you can use its relationships methods to fetch information.

Comment: May I get relationship codes for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to above current Database structure following is the relationships between the tables.

- Posts & comments = OneToMany
- Comments & Replies = OneToMany

[You can read more about relationships in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Hence you need to provide following code in respective model.

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * Get all comments assign to single post
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','post_id');
    }
}

class Comment extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * Get all replies assign to single comment
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reply','comment_id ');
    }
}
```

Now you have got all the posts from DB:

```
$posts = Post::all();
if($posts->count() > 0) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        // single post information
        $comments = $post->comments;
        if($comments->count() > 0) {
            foreach($comments as $comment) {
                // single comment information 
                 $replies = $comment->replies;
                 if($replies->count() > 0) {
                    foreach($replies as $reply) {
                        // single reply information 
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have fetch single post:

```
$post = Post::find($postId);
if($post->count() > 0) {
    $comments = $post->comments;
    if($comments->count() > 0) {
        foreach($comments as $comment) {
            // single comment information 
             $replies = $comment->replies;
             if($replies->count() > 0) {
                foreach($replies as $reply) {
                    // single reply information 
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will eat my memory when post and comment get larger in number, how do I chunk it ?

Comment: You can show comments with limit and provided load more button to load respective comments and replies.